# Multiple objects with different user inputs java

Tags: java, constructor

So I'm trying to get multiple user inputs inside of different objects created in my main driver class, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Other tutorials over the web only show how to do it for one object, but I have multiple.

```
public class roulettedriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyin = new Scanner(System.in);

        // initializing the six players of the game

        Player player1 = new Player(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Player player2 = new Player(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Player player3 = new Player(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Player player4 = new Player(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Player player5 = new Player(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Player player6 = new Player(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

In my other class Player

```
public class Player {

int number1;
int number2;
int number3;
int number4;
int number5;
// constructor for each player at the table
public Player(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4, int number5) {

    this.number1 = number1;
    this.number2 = number2;
    this.number3 = number3;
    this.number4 = number4;
    this.number5 = number5;
```

So I'm trying to get the user input with `keyin.nextInt()` to be the number1,number2,number3,number4,number5, for EACH player, but I can't figure out how to do it!

Comment: Well try that tutorial you mentioned for one `Player` when you get it to work it might reveal the answer.

Comment: @DimaMaligin I tried and for my tests, it changes the input for player2,3,4,5 also when I try to set the int values for player1

Comment: You should use arrays or lists for this purpose. Not sure if you have reached a level where you have learned about arrays and lists though.

Comment: Forget other players for a min there, create only **one** `Player` and get the input for it. Then after you get one `Player` to work do the same with all the others.

Comment: @DimaMaligin I just tried again, it gives me an error for duplicate variables when I try the same method on player2

Comment: don't declare the variables again, just use them.

Comment: `int a = keyin.nextInt()` use `a` then just `a = keyIn.nextInt()` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the standard 'patterns' you will see used in this situation is a 'factory'. That is essentially a specialist class that's only job is to make objects of another class. In your case the 'factory' would be `PlayerFactory` that has a method that can take a `Scanner` and create a `Player` from it. It can have several ways of creating players available. Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
class PlayerFactory {
    public Player makeFromScanner(Scanner scannerIn) {
        int number1 = scannerIn.nextInt();
        int number2 = scannerIn.nextInt();
        ...
        return new Player(number1, number2, ...);
    }

    public Player makeRandom() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number1 = rand.nextInt();
        ...
        return new Player(number1, number2, ...);
    }
}
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
PlayerFactory factory = new PlayerFactory();
Player player1 = factory.makeFromScanner(scannerIn);
Player player2 = factory.makeRandom();
```

Other options are to make this one of the `Player` constructors:

```
class Player {
    public Player(Scanner scannerIn) {
        number1 = scannerIn.nextInt();
        number2 = scannerIn.nextInt();
        ...
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
Player player1 = new Player(scannerIn);
```

Or you could make the build method a static method of `Player`:

```
class Player {
    public static Player makeFromScanner(Scanner scannerIn) {
        ...
    }

    public static Player makeRandom() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is then used as:

```
Player player1 = Player.makeFromScanner(scannerIn);
```

Comment: Do you think I could implement this inside my player class?

Comment: Yes you could make this a static inner class or a static method.

Comment: I've added options for making it a constructor or a static method.

Comment: To me, that's more like a factory

Comment: @dragon66 It is. The *builder pattern* uses "setter" methods to build the desired object like  `new ObjectBuilder(mandatoryValue).withOptional1(...).withOptional2(...).build();`.

Comment: @sprinter Thanks! would you know how to do it in another way, for example instead of user inputted, have it be randomly generated but the number being within an array of ints?

Comment: @Tom yes you're right - I meant factory. Will change.

Comment: @PatrickBui yes you can have as many of these as you want. Will add examples.

Answer (score 0):

May be you try this:

```
public static void main(String[] s) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
    try   
    {   
        String numbers = null;
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter a five numbers (only numbers) or type kill, plis:");   
            numbers = br.readLine();//read a console value typed for user
            if(numbers!=null && numbers.equals("kill")){//verify to continue running or exit
                System.out.println("Exit");
                break;
            }
            int[] numbersToParam = new int[5]; //array for the five parameters to your Player object
            for(int i=0; i<numbers.length(); i++){
                numbersToParam[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(i, i+1));//parse 5 values to array
            }
            //create a new playes with parameters
            new Player(numbersToParam[0],numbersToParam[1],numbersToParam[2],numbersToParam[3],numbersToParam[4]);
        }

    }   
    catch (IOException io)   
    {   
        System.err.println(io.toString()); 

    }



}
```